# Can Xcode run smoothly on Macbook 12" for non ios development?

Tags: xcode, macos

I'm getting a new mac the macbook 12" 2015 and my question is? Can it be use to non ios development like c++ os x programs or etc nothing that include virtual box.

Comment: Yes it can and it will be fine.

Comment: I know the answer is based on opinion but is the recourses eating monsters is the similator for ios or is it xcode itself?

Comment: It really depends on what the code is doing and how much memory and CPU grunt you have.  However I think it will be fine for normal development.

Comment: So i conclude i may edit almost any code but i cannot run it always and sorry for reasking but 1300$ is a lot

Comment: Yeah you'll be able to edit everything and run the vast majority.

Comment: I'm doing development for a computational fluid dynamics code on my MacBook Air. Of course it is not the fastest in compiling large libraries or executables, but works just fine. Executing the code is okay for testing purposes, since the production system is on a HPC cluster anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you are using to code. If you are coding with light text editors like sublime or notepad++ it will be fast and snappy. Other heavier IDEs might slow it down a bit.

From my experience with it Xcode will run OK, but simulator will run noticebly slower than a MBP. Also remember that a clean compile of a big project is a heavy task, but once its done compiler only compiles small parts of the project, so compile times are very fast.

I think using the new MB as a secondary portable machine to use on the go alongside with a more powerfull machine (for heavy lifting tasks) is the perfect setup